# SSH from Windows10 to Windows10 on lan, not able to use DIR command

Tags: windows-10, ssh, sshd

When using OpenSSH from Win 10 to Win 10 laptops on local network - I am not able to view hidden files and folders. The Dir command behaves different between being on the local laptop and on the remote laptop using SSHD, which is natively build into Win10.

**Example:**

I log in as the administrator user (both laptops are mine and connected directly), but the command `dir -Force` is only showing this message: "*Volume in drive C is Windows-SSD ... File Not Found.*"
I know the command works when used on the local laptop. Is there some restrictions, when loged on to the remote SSHD server? Or does SSH limit commands?

Thanks in advance - I am new to this, hope for some kind of understanding.

Comment: Are you sure you're talking to PowerShell on the remote system, rather than CMD? In PowerShell, `dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`, which does take a `-force` optional parameter; on CMD, `dir` is a built-in command that does not use `-Force` - you'd want `/A` instead.

Comment: "When using OpenSSH from Win 10 to Win 10 laptops on local network" - What console are you using PowerShell or Command Prompt?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin  Ramhound        You are great. A combo of both your answers lead me to the result and realization of what it is to be a Noob.  On the client I logged in via SSH and ended up in cmd on remote server.  I had used both cmd and powershell and a bit of frustration. In the mess I did not notice that because I logged in as administrator on both cmd and powershell, it starts out in different folders for once. That was one nooby mistake, not to notice. Testing from C:\ both remote and local, but did it with powershell to cmd did no good.    Thank you for your answer / comment both of you.